# How to load JS as the first item in head tag?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

We have a custom module that has a JS library that we want to load in the `<head>` tag as the very first item even before all the normal Drupal JS files. All other libraries are loaded through `mytheme.libraries.yml`.

How can I load the library (`mymodule/myscript`) so that it loads as the first `<script>` tag in the `<head>`?

What we tried:

#### mymodule.module

```
function  mymodule_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/myscript';
}
```

#### mymodule.libraries.yml

```
myscript:
  version: 1.x
  header: true
  js:
    /path/to/file: { external: true, weight: -200 }
```

Current problem:

```
<head>
  <script>script1</script>
  <script>script2</script>
  <script>myscript is loaded here</script>
</head>
```

Goal:

```
<head>
  <script>myscript is loaded here</script>
  <script>script1</script>
  <script>script2</script>
</head>
```

Comment: You can user `hook_page_attachments()` in which you can attach your JS library in `$page['#attached']['html_head'][]`.

For more info check this link: [Click here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2015-12-30/adding-javascript-file-to-head-drupal-8)

Comment: @Manav the link you shared was able to get me my answer i seeked, I added my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using @Manav's link, i was able to get to this solution that worked.

```
function mymodule_page_attachments(&$attachments) {
  $custom_script = [
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'script',
    '#attributes' => [
      'src' => 'path/to/file.js',
    ],
    '#weight' => -200, // this allowed me to do what i needed
  ];

  $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$custom_script, 'custom_script_key'];
}
```