# Is there a way to attach HTML in <head> after the css links?

Tags: 8, hooks

We currently can add HTML attachment to the `<head>` section like this.

```php
function mymodule_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {
  $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    // some HTML declaration
  ];
}
```

But the attached items are always rendered before all the CSS and Javascript links. Is there a way to attach anything to after the CSS and JS links in `<head>`?

Comment: You could add it in [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21html.html.twig/8.2.x) after the `js-placeholder` line.

Comment: Thanks. But as a module developer, I do not have access to html.html.twig of my users, so that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you tried add a weight like mentionned here : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264619/how-to-load-js-as-the-first-item-in-head-tag ?

Comment: Weight doesn't work because JS and CSS are in different placeholder that are hard-coded to render and display after `html_head`.